# WHERE clause vs Smaller table

Tags: query-optimization, amazon-redshift

Is there a meaningful difference (or a rule of thumb for a given table size) for query time of a table with a WHERE clause limiting the result set compared to a smaller table which is equal to the size of the post-WHERE, limited result set?

For example:

1. Your table has records with timestamps spanning many years. You run a query that contains a WHERE clause limiting your result to the last 10 days only.
2. Your table has only 10 days of data, and you run the same query as above (obviously without the WHERE clause since it's not necessary in this case).

Should I expect a query performance difference in the two scenarios above? Note that I'm using Redshift. Obviously there is a $$ cost savings of storing less data, which is one benefit of scenario 2. Any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on the table and the indexes (in case of Redshift the Sort Key). Traditionally if you have a descending index on the timestamp and use the timestamp on the where clause, then the query engine will pretty quickly find the records it needs and stop looking.

There may still be some benefit from having less records, perhaps even maintaining two tables, but duplicating data should be a very last resort if testing shows that the performance benefit is real and necessary.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - the question is about Redshift - Redshift does not have indexes.

Comment: @JonScott I updated the answer to include Redshift terminology `Sort Key` which serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In Redshift, The answer is yes, it is always quicker to query a smaller table rather than a where clause on a larger table. This is because Redshift will generally scan all of the rows in the table. or at least those rows which are not excluded by the distribution/sort key optimisations.

Lets also address the other important aspects of this question

In almost all cases Redshift storage is cheap - that is because storage is usually not the deciding factor when capacity planning a Redshift cluster. It is more about getting the performance you need for the queries that you want to run.

1. You can improve the performance of Redshift queries in 4 ways
   Increase the size of the cluster.
2. Tune the query.
3. Alter the definition of the Redshift tables, taking into account
   contents and usage patterns. Sort and Distribution keys can make a
   big difference. compression types should also be considered.
4. Implement Redshift performance management, to give priority to
   higher priority queries.